# Ввод n элементов в одну строку

Tags: python, список

Вот программа:

```
i = 1
k = 0
p = 0
n = int(input())
for i in range(1, n+1):
  a = int(input())
  if a % 2 == 0:
    k += 1
  if a % 2 != 0:
    p += 1
print(abs(k-p))
```

Элементы можно вводит в терминал только так:

```
3
1
2
3
```

А нужно вот так:

```
3
1 2 3
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: Если не секрет, результат вашего примера показывает что ?

Comment: Модуль разницы количества парных и непарных чисел.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

можно разбить строку на числа:

```
i = [int(a) for a in input().split()]
```

пояснение:
`input()` содержит введённую строку, `.split()` разбивает её по пробельным символам, *создавая список* полученных значений, дальше каждый элемент этого списка превращается в `int`, и добавляется в список `i`

Это выражение аналогично следующему:

```
i = []
for a in input().split():
    i.append( int(a) )
```

результат:

```
 IN: "12 214  5 24 5"
 OUT: [12, 214, 5, 24, 5]
```

использование в вашей программе:

```
i = 1
k = 0
p = 0
n = int(input()) # не будет использоваться
nums = [int(a) for a in input().split()]
for a in nums:
  if a % 2 == 0:
    k += 1
  if a % 2 != 0:
    p += 1
print(abs(k-p))
```

Comment: А можно ли сделать ввод таким, чтоб можно было и в строку и тут же с переводом на другую строку. И все это пока не упрется в конкретные рамки и ввод запретится.
Например:
24653 676
4678
567 578 И все это бы в один массив попало. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
input1 = list(map(int, '12 214 5 24 5'.split()))
input2 = [int(a) for a in '11 213 4 23 5'.split()]

print(input1)  # [12, 214, 5, 24, 5]
print(*input2)  # 11 213 4 23 5

from itertools import chain
print(*chain(input1, input2))  # 12 214 5 24 5 11 213 4 23 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю такой вариант

```
n=int(input())

a=map(int, input().split(maxsplit=n))

print(sum(a))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]